# How to merge multiple queries into a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 queries I want to execute at one time. Is there any shortcut without hitting DataBase multiple times and with minimum query length?

```
select studentId, student_status 
from students 
where student_dob='2012-04-04' and student_name like %test1%

select studentId, student_status 
from students 
where student_dob='2012-06-04' and student_name like %test2%

select studentId, student_status 
from students 
where student_dob='2012-05-04' and student_name like %test3%`
  ..
  .
  .
select studentId, student_status 
from students 
where student_dob='2012-07-04' and student_name like %test-n%
```

I tried:

```
select studentId, student_status 
from students where
  (student_dob='2012-04-04' and  student_name like %test1%) ||
  (student_dob='2012-06-04' and student_name like %test2%) ||
  (student_dob='2012-05-04' and student_name like %test3%) ||
  .
  .
  .
  (student_dob='2012-07-04' and student_name like %test-n%)
group by studentId
```

This query becoming too lengthy, can anyone make it short? because of thousands of records in my database.

Comment: There are two queries, but they don`t seem to match, the date in second example does not change, it always '2012-04-04', but in first query, it changes. I want to ask what is the pattern here

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use IN operator, something like this,

```
select 
  studentId, 
  student_status 
from 
  students 
where 
  student_dob in (
    '2012-04-04', '2012-06-04', '2012-05-04'
  ) 
  and student_name like '%test%'
```

Comment: i want the answer to be selected in manner where students Id ,status  having same dob and same name